# conditional statements not working in outlook

Tags: html-email, email-templates

I could not found similar answer elsewhere so posting here.I have one email rendering issue in outlook email client for ios devices. Email template is using the older and evergreen ghost table [concept](https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso/#ghost-tables) to centre the table layout in email template.

To make table work only in mso it wraps the table in this condition

```
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:transparent;"><tr><td align="center"><![endif]-->
<div class="col num12">
<!-- whateveremail content bla bla-->
</div>
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
```

and as such, the email should render table only in mso devices which is outlook.

But this technique is not rendering the actual table in outlook apps(android/ios both) or even in outlook email in web which it should and layout still looks broken.

As of now i have made this work by removing the conditions but seems not to be the best practices so please suggest.

Comment: webmail also still requires you to inline the code, since it mostly doesn't use embedded CSS

Comment: Outlook apps both modern techniques as mentioned by Frankenstein. You don't need conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

MSO conditions are for the Windows Desktop versions of Outlook. mobile apps and webmail use more broader and modern targeting techniques. See https://howtotarget.email/ and search 'Outlook' to find more appropriate techniques for your use case.